# How to prevent UNDO on guternberg block editor

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

I have one flag in my plugin, and when it active i want to disable UNDO function in post gutenberg editor.

Can someone help me to achieve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: in simple term, when certain condition meet, I want to disable UNDO function in Gutenberg post editor. So user cant do any UNDO action.